# Calendar extender day calculation exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code that I did on calendar extender using ajax toolscript. I want to calculate days but it gives the following exception

> Unable to cast object of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender'
>   to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Here is the code for calculating days::

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox2_CalendarExtender.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        TextBox2_CalendarExtender.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);

        TextBox1_CalendarExtender.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        TextBox1_CalendarExtender.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan days = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1_CalendarExtender).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2_CalendarExtender));
        int day = Convert.ToInt32(days.TotalDays);
        Label1.Text = day.ToString();
    }
```

and this is the asp code for that particular section only::

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox2_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="TextBox2" StartDate="<%#DateTime.Now %>" EndDate="     <%#DateTime.Now.AddDays(30) %>">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="TextBox1" StartDate="<%#DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) %>" EndDate="<%#DateTime.Now.AddDays(30) %>">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from your `Convert` method. The code `TimeSpan days = Convert.ToDateTime(new object()).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now));`
 will give the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.

However if you change the *new object()* to a valid Type of one of the [method signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it works without error.

In your code ,this line

```
TimeSpan days = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1_CalendarExtender).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2_CalendarExtender));
```

`TextBox1_CalendarExtender` and `TextBox2_CalendarExtender` need to have either the  `StartDate` or `EndDate` Property appended so that they are of Type DateTime. The convert isn't needed since converting a DateTime to a DateTime doesn't do anything.  It will look something like this in the end.

```
TimeSpan days = TextBox1_CalendarExtender.StartDate.Subtract(TextBox2_CalendarExtender.StartDate);
```

Comment: where in the design mode of this page and in the <asp:textbox tag.

Comment: @user2334012 You didn't post any asp code here so I don't really understand your question.

Comment: i have given th asp code now and I am still getting he same exception.